# How to join dataframes based on column containing value as a list

Tags: python, list, dataframe, join

I have a dataframe

df1:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,[1, 2]],
               [2,[3, 4]],
               [3,[5, 6,1,1]]],
              columns=['person','brand_id'])
```

Another dataframe which has brand names for the brand_id is

```
cars={1:'BMW',2:'HONDA',3:'HYUNDAI',4:'KIA',5:'FORD',6:'TESLA'}
df2=pd.DataFrame(list(cars.items()),columns = ['id','brand_name'])
```

I need to substitute/join on column brand_id so that it gets replaced by brand names from df2:

Output should look like

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6Ktf.png)

I tried to split brand_id to multiple columns and then join with df2 but was unable to merge back and also it does not look the right way as values in the list varies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map it directly from `cars` dictionary using a nested list comprehension and dictionary lookup

```py
df['brand_name'] = [[cars[k] for k in row if cars.get(k)] for row in df.brand_id]
print(df)

   person      brand_id               brand_name
0       1        [1, 2]             [BMW, HONDA]
1       2        [3, 4]           [HYUNDAI, KIA]
2       3  [5, 6, 1, 1]  [FORD, TESLA, BMW, BMW]
```